# Setting upper and lower bound to the values plotted in a matrix with plot.matrix

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I am trying to plot the values of a matrix and I need to do it using the `library(plot.matrix)`. My problem is that some of the matrix have extremely high values which bias the plot and do not allow me to observe graphically the differences of the non-outliers' values.

To illustrate this, imagine I want to plot the following matrix:

```
> a <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
> a[1,3] <- 1000
> a
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2 1000
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

Therefore, I would like to avoid considering the `a[1,3]` value when plotting the matrix (I do not want it to be considered when defining the breaks of the palette or other plot settings).

After checking the documentation [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot.matrix/vignettes/plot.matrix.htmlI](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot.matrix/vignettes/plot.matrix.html) did not find any argument for the function plot plot.matrix which directly allows me to define the range of values to plot - something similar to the x.lim or y.lim arguments.

Although I already have some other solutions:

- Redefine the matrix substituting these values for `NA`
- Use an adequate definition of breaks

I was wondering if there is any direct argument to the fuction `plot(...)` that allows me to do this directly.

Comment: Have you seen the `heatmap` function? It has the `scale` argument that deal exactly with your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `breaks` argument to set the limits manually:

```
plot(a, breaks=c(0,10))
```

[image]

Or even to set all the individual breaks:

```
plot(a, breaks=c(0,2.5,5,7.5,10))
```

[image]